# What Does the Exclamation means in ServiceInsight near Processing Time?

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

There is a little exclamation mark next to the processing time in ServiceInsight. Anyone has any idea what it means? I can't find any information on the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an indication of a [clock drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift). Essentially it means the message was processed before it was sent, which happens if the sender and receiver endpoints are different machines and their clocks are not in sync. It is also documented [here](https://docs.particular.net/monitoring/metrics/definitions#metrics-captured-critical-time).